Not all .xsd files are generated after JDK 17 upgrade
I've just upgraded an old web service from java 11, spring boot 2.7.x to Java 17 and spring boot 3.4.x.  Finally got the WSDL to come up.  However, I noticed that the content of the WSDL was not generated correctly, compared to the existing version.  Upon a closer look, I found that the old version generates about 21 or so .xsd files in the /target/wsdl directory.  Whereas this upgraded version only generated 3 .xsd files!
I'm new to soap web services.  Where can I check to see why the .xsd files are not all generated?
This is what I have in my pom.xml.  Thank you!
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>iway.ws.QueryWS  </sei>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <extension>false</extension>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <xdebug>true</xdebug>
                            <resourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</resourceDestDir>
                            
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


Turned out, there is a new version of schema that I needed to use.  I was using the old version when I was upgrading to Java 17 and the results were missing .xsd files that were generated when using jaxws-maven-plugin.
